# The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DocumentSnapshot'

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I just updated to Dart2 and Flutter sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0' and now I got an error:

```
return Scaffold(
  body: FutureBuilder(
    future: usersRef.doc(widget.accountiD).get(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return buildLoading();
      }
      UserAccount currentUser = UserAccount.fromDocument(snapshot.data);
      return ListView(
        children: []
      );
    }
  ),
);
```

The error was on the **snapshot.data** saying **The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DocumentSnapshot'.**
What to do? I need help.

Comment: Try `FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
return Scaffold(
  body: FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
    future: usersRef.doc(widget.accountiD).get(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return buildLoading();
      }
      UserAccount currentUser = UserAccount.fromDocument(snapshot.data.data()); //you need to add "data()" to access the map of objects inside snapshot.data
      return ListView(
        children: []
      );
    }
  ),
);
```

Comment: Hey @Huthaifa thank you for this, it worked! But I don't need to add **.data()** on my snapshot.data. Because on my UserAccount screen I've actually make all my fields to **.data()** for example
```
factory UserAccount.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
  return UserAccount(
    id: doc.data()!['id'],
    email: doc.data()!['email'],
  );
}
```
The only thing that I did with my snapshot was this **snapshot.data!**
I added **!** at the end. And I was able to get my data. Anyways thank you for the suggestion it worked. Thank you and take care!

Comment: You are most welcome! Glad it worked out. :)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem a while ago and just had it again and had forgotten the solution which brought me here.

The solution I had found was using the ["as"](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#keywords) keyword

### Example

```dart
snapshot.data as int
```

or

```dart
snapshot.data as String
```

Just do the same with any other data type.
Hope it helps. Answer sent from .

Answer (score 1):

```
return Scaffold(
  body: FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
    future: usersRef.doc(widget.accountiD).get(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return buildLoading();
      }
      UserAccount currentUser = UserAccount.fromDocument(snapshot.data!); //(Add after snapshot.data)
        return ListView(
          children: []
        );
    }
  ),
);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You may try ***UserAccount.fromDocument(snapshot as DocumentSnapshot);*** This kind of casting may help to convert your need of Object convertion of DocumentSnapshot.

Answer (score 0):

Working code in 2022. It listens to changes on the document and updates it:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('tasks')
            .doc('B2tRytXodOwoYA1U4gK2')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
      
          TaskModel task =
              TaskModel.fromSnapshot(snapshot.data as DocumentSnapshot);
          return Text(task.category);
        });
  }
}
```

You need a model like following:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

    class TaskModel {
      String _category = '';
      String get category => _category;
    
      TaskModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
        _category = snapshot['category'];
       
      }
    }
```

Or you can get values as a map instead without having a class.